# Typescript 1.0 compile on save ignores errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

is there a way to force the compile-on-save to fail when there is an error? Currently it generates the javascript output despite the fact that there are errors in the code.

the build time compilation works fine and stops at any errors but it seems that compiler just ignores errors when compiling on save.

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of error. The compiler tries to generate the javascript if it can e.g. a typescript file:

```
foo = 123;
```

will compile just fine (even though you need to do `var foo`). But a file like this:

```
class d
```

is too bad an error for the compiler to understand and therefore it cannot generate any javascript.

Comment: so why this behaviour is different between compile-on-save and build time compile? any idea? can we somehow ask VS/typescript to have the same strictness when compiling on save?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. `tsc` will still emit code in the presence of type errors, but not syntax errors.